# Regex match blank between "--"

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an issue with a regex. here below details:

I have the following basis chain:
N_aa-AAAA-140143-AAAAAA_1---

The regex i'm using:

```
^N_([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9_-éÉ\s]+)---
```

> The result i have for the basis chain:
> group1: aa.
> group2: AAAA.
> group3: 140143.
> group4: AAAAAA_1.

But sometimes there is some missing element between "--" for the group3:
N_AA-AA--AAAA_1---

> The result i would like in this case:
> group1: aa.
> group2: AAAA.
> group3: blank (nothing).
> group4: AAAAAA_1.

Thanks for your help ;-).

Comment: Use `*` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 3rd group is optional then use the `*` quantifier (0 or many occurrences) instead of `+` (at least 1 or many occurrences):

```
^N_([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]*)-([A-Za-z0-9_-éÉ\s]+)---
```

See it passing your 2 test-cases here:
https://regex101.com/r/DWStTX/1